# C++: implementing a higher-order function which receives a lambda as an input

Tags: c++, lambda, types, return-type, higher-order-functions

Let's take a look at the following function:

```
auto F(vector <int> *p) {
  return [p](int y) -> int{ return y + (*p)[0]; };
}
```

It does a pretty simple thing: it receives a pointer at a vector of integers and returns a lambda which has another integer as an input and returns the result of adding this integer to the first element of the vector we have a pointer at. 
If I want to implement a higher-order function which could accept such a lambda as input, I, obviously, cannot use the `auto` in the prototype. I tried fixing it like this:

```
typedef int *A (int);

A F(vector <int> *p) {
      return [p](int y) -> int{ return y + (*p)[0]; };
    }
```

But that implementation brings about a conflict as well: the lambda type cannot be converted to `A`.

How could this be implemented?

Comment: assign the Lambda to a std::function and return the std::function

Comment: [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @Brian I can use it as the return type - I cannot convert it to any type I can use in the prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried fixing it like this:

```
typedef int *A (int);

A F(vector <int> *p) {
      return [p](int y) -> int{ return y + (*p)[0]; };
}
```

> ... the lambda type cannot be converted to `A`.

This would make sense in principle only for a completely stateless lambda. Your lambda has a capture, which means it has state that needs to be stored somewhere, which means it *must* be a callable object rather than a simple free function.

Your options are:

1. Implement the higher-order function as a template on the lower-order type:

   ```
   template <typename Func>
   int higherOrder(int x, Func&& f)
   {
     return f(x);
   }
   ```

   or
2. Wrap the lambda inside something with a well-known type, usually

   ```
   int higherOrder(int x, std::function<int(int)> const &f)
   {
     return f(x);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template:

```
template <class Func>
void foo(Func func);

foo(F(p));  // ok; Func deduced to the lambda type
```